# WebClient UploadString Not Working

Tags: c#, web-services, http-post

I have two methods on a web service that I am trying to invoke with WebClient:

```
[Route("TestDownload")]
[HttpGet]
public string TestDownload()
{
    return "downloaded";
}

[Route("TestUpload")]
[HttpPost]
public string TestUpload(string uploaded)
{
    return uploaded;
}
```

This code works:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    var sResult = wc.DownloadString("http://localhost/Website/TestDownload");
    Console.WriteLine(sResult);
}
```

This code throws a System.Net.WebException: (404) Not Found

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    var sResult = wc.UploadString("http://localhost/Website/TestUpload", "test");
    Console.WriteLine(sResult);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The `UploadString` on `WebClient` is using the string parameter as the http request body. By default, WebApi supplies controller method parameters for simple types, including string, from the query string (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). To override this behavior and indicate that a string parameter is to be found in the request body, you use the `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
[Route("TestUpload")]
[HttpPost]
public string TestUpload([FromBody] string uploaded)
{
    return uploaded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a  routing  for that controller/method, something like this:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    "yourRouteName", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "yourController", action = "TestUpload", uploaded="" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Ah so I take it this is putting the parameter in the URL string. What if the string is too large to fit (it's actually a serialized object)?